# Getting the cells in a grid between 2 positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I have a grid where I want to get all the cells in an area I dragged with the mouse, i.e all the cells between mouseDown and mouseUp.

I  tried my best but cannot come up with a solution that will work for both positive and negative values.

Say I have this grid, and the red dots are the mouse events:

[image]

I started writing a function to get all the cells in this area, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it while accounting for both negative (dragging down and to the left) and positive (dragging up and to the right) values.

```
public static Vector2Int[,] GetAreaBetweenPositions(Vector2Int mouseDown, Vector2Int mouseUp)
    {
        int diffX = mouseUp.x - mouseDown.x;
        int diffY = mouseUp.y - mouseDown.y;

        Vector2Int[,] area = new Vector2Int[diffX, diffY];

        for (int x = mouseDown.x; x < diffX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = mouseDown.y; y < diffY; y++)
            {
                area[x, y] = new Vector2Int(mouseDown.x + x, mouseDown.y + y);
            }
        }

        return area;
    }
```

Comment: You do not say what platform you are using, however, “most” grids have a “selected” cells collection. Thus eliminating all the posted code.

Comment: @JohnG Not quite sure what you mean. I am interested in the solution to this math problem, the platform should be irrelevant? Maybe Im misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

While I have not fully tested this, I think I found a solution:

```
public static Vector2Int[,] GetAreaBetweenPositions(Vector2Int mouseDown, Vector2Int mouseUp)
{
    int dirX = mouseUp.x > mouseDown.x ? 1 : -1;
    int dirY = mouseUp.y > mouseDown.y ? 1 : -1;

    int diffX = Mathf.Abs(mouseUp.x - mouseDown.x);
    int diffY = Mathf.Abs(mouseUp.y - mouseDown.y);

    Vector2Int[,] area = new Vector2Int[diffX + 1, diffY + 1];

    for (int x = 0; x < area.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < area.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            area[x, y] = new Vector2Int(mouseDown.x + (x * dirX), mouseDown.y + (y * dirY));
        }
    }
    
    return area;
}
```